# Is there a way to track App Store visitors?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Is there a way to track visitors to the App Store? I'd like to find out how many people are viewing my app's App Store page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to see how many App store visitors you get for your App unless they buy/download your App (or leave a review), but check out the [iTunes Connect App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect-mobile/id376771144?mt=8).  It is one of the best ways to track everything you can track about your Apps.

> The [iTunes Connect] app goes into good detail, allowing you to break down sales by
>   day, week, month and six months. Complete with graphs that display
>   sold units and updates, you can also see how your apps are doing in
>   all the markets they are being sold in.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless they post a comment, you can't know who is visiting your page.

Answer (score 1):

There are third party services too that give in-deapth analytics. A few to name are:
http://www.flurry.com, http://www.appannie.com and
http://www.appfigures.com